# ¿Qué es “la catalítica” a la que se refiere este artículo?

Tags: significado, vocabulario-técnico

En [este articulo](http://www.elmundo.es/cronica/2017/11/14/5a074f75e5fdea43778b469c.html) sobre un señor que pinta unos cuadros que valen una pasta gansa, él explica sus inicios en la pintura en una academia de dibujo. Como contexto, él en esos momento tiene 14 años. No ha visto nunca antes a una mujer desnuda pero en esa academia una vez a la semana una modelo posa desnuda para que la retranten sin ropa (y él lo flipa, claro). El artista explica sobre esa experiencia:

> Todas ellas [las modelos] estaban de muy buen año. Los lápices echaban humo. La luz rojiza de la **catalítica** afrancesaba la escena. Y así... una mezcla de hormonas y grafito... fui aprendiendo a dibujar encantado de la vida.

Por el contexto entiendo que "**la catalítica**" debe de ser algún tipo de lámpara, pues desprende una luz rojiza, pero no necesariamente. Puede ser algún otro tipo de instrumento (como una estufilla para mantener la temperatura del taller y que la modelo no pase frío).

La definición del DRAE no parece aplicar en este contexto, pues [catalítico](http://dle.rae.es/?id=7u72ZZn) es "Perteneciente o relativo a la catálisis." y esta a su vez es el

> Incremento de la velocidad de una reacción en presencia de un catalizador.

y no entiendo como aplicaría esa definición al contexto de la cita, especialmente debido a la referencia a la luz rojiza.

¿Qué es “la catalítica” a la que se hace referencia en esa cita este artículo?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Parece que se trata de una estufa <sup>[1](http://www.huffingtonpost.es/angel-tristan/regreso-a-la-catalitica_b_14332130.html)</sup>:

> En muchas ciudades y lugares de Galicia, como en Santa Marta de Ortigueira, donde paso unos días, se acabaron las existencias de estufas catalíticas. A mal tiempo..., soluciones de emergencia y apropiadas a los esquilmados tiempos que vivimos. "Volvemos al gas", comentaba la dependienta de una tienda de electrodomésticos.

Y acá la explicación de [estufa catalítica](http://estufas.org.es/cataliticas%20Estufas%20catal%C3%ADticas):

> Las estufas catalíticas típicas implican unos pocos componentes primarios, al ser una superficie de calefacción más integral. En la mayoría de los calentadores catalíticos, hay una placa delgada de platino que es el componente activo para acelerar la reacción química. Esta placa de platino se calienta eléctricamente a más de 150 grados C. Esta superficie, cuando se calienta de manera uniforme, reacciona produciendo más energía en forma de calor.

Parece que las [nuevas](http://zona-hogar.com/estufas-cataliticas/) dan una llama azul:

> Las estufas catalíticas funcionan con gas butano y en la actualidad la mayoría de los modelos funcionan a través de la tecnología denominada “**llama azul**”, que funcionan mediante un sistema de convección térmica con el que se genera una mayor temperatura durante el proceso, ahorrando energía.

Pero buscando modelos más antiguos:

[image]

Así que por eso me imagino que se habla de la luz roja.